# Backbone - Mocha - not calling 'this.fetched.done' in onRender function of view

Tags: unit-testing, backbone.js, promise, mocha.js, sinon

While writing the **tests** for the following snippet of `Backbone` code, more specifically a `Marionette ItemView`, I run into the issue that when I render my view in `test.html` and the `onRender` function of the view is called, however `this.fetched.done(function () {console.log('HELLO')});` does not output anything.

`this.fetched = this.model.fetch();` is set in the `initialize` function of my view.

I am using `Mocha`, `Chai` and `Sinon` for my tests.

I have tried to force my code to call the `done` method by stubbing the `fetch` method in the model in the `beforeEach` function where I do most of my test set-up.

```
this.fetchStub = sinon.stub(my.Model.prototype, 'fetch', function () {
    return {
        done : function () {
            return sinon.spy();
        }
    }
 });
```

When running the test it does trigger the `done` method in the stub but never the output of the original promise.

I have also tried creating a `sinon.fakeServer` and having it return the desired object, but I still do not get the output from the original `done` method.

How do I get my tests to actually force my code down the desired path?

This is the code I'm trying to test:

```
initialize: function (options) {
        // do other stuff
        this.fetched = this.model.fetch();
},

onRender: function () {

        var that = this;

        this.fetched.done(

            function (model, response, options) {
                console.log('Here');
                // Do other stuff here .....
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: Who calls `onRender()`? Seems to me that if you want that trigger to fire you need to call `this. onRender();` inside your `initialize()` after `this.fetched = this.model.fetch();`.

Comment: Sorry @JavierBuzzi, I forgot to mention that it is a `Marionette ItemView`.  However the `onRender` function is called, as I mention in my question, so why would I call it manually? What doesn't get output when running my tests in the console.log of the `done` method.

Comment: @hyprstack is `onRender` a marionette method that gets called automatically..?

Comment: @TJ it gets triggered after the view has been rendered http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.3/marionette.itemview.html#events-and-callback-methods

Comment: Presumably you mean `this.fetched.done(...);` does not output anything, ie `.fetched` not `.fetch`

Comment: @Roamer-1888 yes. my mistake there with the typo. too much going on

Comment: It's not completely clear why you would need `this.fetched.done(...)` in the `onRender` handler. According to the doc'n, the `onRender` event is "triggered after the view has been rendered" and the `el` "is full of the view's HTML, ready to go", so I would guess that the model must already be in place at the time `onRender` fires - the asynchronicity having been managed by Backbone/Marrionette internally?

Comment: It's not clear because I'm not showing all my code. Trying to keep it to a minimum of a non working version of my code. I need it in the `onRender` function because I need markup to exist in the `DOM` when the `subviews` are instantiated and also use the model from the parent view, for which I need to be certain the model is correctly populated.

Comment: OK, I think I understand. But if what I said is correct, then `this.fetched.done(...)` should never be necessary in the onRender` handler, whatever it does. The same cannot be said about `initialize`, in which `this.model.fetch().done(...)` is a realistic necessity.